# long script error internet explorer

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

Please can someone help?

I've had facebook integration scripts running on my website for many years already with no problem.  However, I am now being flooded with complaints from customers who use INTERNET EXPLORER saying that since an update to IE a week or so ago they are constantly getting the long-running script errors...

```
"Stop Running This Script.
A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. 
 If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive."
```

I've worked it out (by disabling scripts) that the problem is with the Facebook scripts.

Nothing has been changed in months on the website so it's not something I can figure out how to fix.

Scripts: Invite your friends, Like, Share page, etc

Please, please help

Thanks
Matt

Comment: I'm afraid there are not enough details. At the very least, what version of IE are your customer using?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue.  I can reproduce the issue not just on my site, but on others as well when using IE 9 or IE 10 (have not tested with older IE versions).  The issue seems to be a result of IE's compatibility view feature.  If that is enabled for a website, which also has the facebook like button on the page of the site you're trying to load, a long running script error is produced  (error from a function called _t).  When I disable compatibility view for that website, the error goes away.  I'm not sure if the issue is with the IE feature, or with facebook's button...I'm not getting same error from other scripts, nor other social buttons like google+, which makes me think the issue is on Facebook's end.  I've been trying different IE setting configs for days now...so far, the only fix I can come up with is turn compatibility view off.  And of course resolve issues so that compatibility view are not needed.  Though telling your users they have to turn off compatibility view doesn't seem like an appropriate response...so I hope a better fix is found.